# Cambiar clases CSS de un SVG con botones HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

¿Cómo podría cambiar los valores de [`stroke-dasharray`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/) de tal forma que al momento de cambiar su valor cambie de clase y de color?.

Como se muestra en fiddle tengo 3 botones. Al presionar **8 am** se ponga al 100% y al presionar **12 pm** aparezca 50% y **4 pm** al 20% y, de ser posible, el texto de la clase `percentage`.

```css
.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  
  .single-chart {
    width: 33%;
    justify-content: space-around ;
  }
  
  .circular-chart {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
  
  .circle-bg {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #eee;
    stroke-width: 3.8;
  }
  
  .circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.8;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes progress {
    0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
    }
  }
  
  .circular-chart.orange .circle {
    stroke: #ff9f00;
  }
  
  .circular-chart.green .circle {
    stroke: #4CC790;
  }
  
  .circular-chart.red .circle {
    stroke: #e53c3c;
  }
  
  .percentage {
    fill: #SDFASF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    text-anchor: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="single-chart">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart red">
        <path class="circle-bg"
            d="M18 2.0845
                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
            />
        <path class="circle"
            stroke-dasharray="20, 100"
            d="M18 2.0845
                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
                a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
                />
        <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">20%</text>
    </svg>
</div>

<button class= "circle " type="button"  name=""  stroke-dasharray="100" onclick="circular-chart green">8:00 AM</button>
<button class= "circle " type="button"  name=""  stroke-dasharray="50" onclick="circular-chart orange">12:00 pm</button>
<button class= "circle " type="button"  name=""  stroke-dasharray="20" onclick="circular-chart red">4:00 pm</button>
```

[Enlace al Fiddle (original).](http://jsfiddle.net/vhr6g70j/)

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?¿Que fallos te está dando?¿Has probado a utilizar la pseudoclase `:focus` de CSS o el evento `onfocus` de Javascript?

Comment: buscare info acerca del  evento y la pseudo clase gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar las clases son con las funciones addClass y removeClass, te deje un ejemplo comentado, se me hizo más fácil hacer una función a la que le mandes el % y ya modifique la propiedad en lugar de estar haciendo una clase para cada %. Pruébalo y me comentas

```js
 function rellenado(id){
  $('.circle').css('stroke-dasharray', id+', 100');
  $('.percentage').html(id + '%');
                /*Para cambiar las clases es con */
 //$('.circle').addClass('circulo50');
 }
```

```css
 
 .flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  
  .single-chart {
    width: 33%;
    justify-content: space-around ;
  }
  
  .circular-chart {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 250px;
  }
  
  .circle-bg {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #eee;
    stroke-width: 3.8;
  }
  
  .circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 2.8;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
  }

  .circle50{
   stroke-dasharray:50,100;
  }
  
  @keyframes progress {
    0% {
      stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
    }
  }
  
  .circular-chart.orange .circle {
    stroke: #ff9f00;
  }
  
  .circular-chart.green .circle {
    stroke: #4CC790;
  }
  
  .circular-chart.red .circle {
    stroke: #e53c3c;
  }
  
  .percentage {
    fill: #SDFASF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    text-anchor: middle;
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="single-chart">
 <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart red">
   <path class="circle-bg"
  d="M18 2.0845
    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
   />
   <path class="circle"
  stroke-dasharray="20, 100"
  d="M18 2.0845
    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
    a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
   />
   <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">20%</text>
 </svg>
</div>

<button id="me" class= "circle " type="button"  name=""  stroke-dasharray="100" onclick="rellenado(100)">8:00 AM</button>
<button class= "circle " type="button"  name=""  stroke-dasharray="50" onclick="rellenado(50)">12:00 pm</button>
<button class= "circle " type="button"  name=""  stroke-dasharray="20" onclick="rellenado(20)">4:00 pm</button>
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Manuel, te agradezco muchisimo

Comment: Cuando este grande quiero ser como tu :D

Comment: De nada, cunado gustes

Comment: Uso edge y veo cambiar el porcentaje pero no la barra está mal o no funciona en edge? el de Oscar si me funciona bien

Comment: Por lo general edge maneja tag diferentes - pruébalo en chrome o firefox

Comment: Tampoco me funcionó en Chrome para Windows. Hace animación inicial hasta el 20% en rojo y luego no cambia la barra nunca más.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas para que tu animación quede bien es hacer uso de transiciones, y no animaciones:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition

De modo que se animará automáticamente cualquier cambio en un atributo CSS.

Además, he almacenado en juegos de datos (`dataset`) la información que debe cambiar, para facilitar actualizar o editar el código HTML:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Y, por último, en vez de usar los atributos HTML `onclick`, he usado `addEventListener`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Con todos estos cambios realizados, este es el resultado:

```js
/* Cuando cargue el DOM agregamos los eventos "clic" */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  /* Precargamos los elementos necesarios */
  let circulo = document.querySelector('svg .circle');
  let porc = document.querySelector('svg .percentage');
  /* Agregamos un evento "clic" a los botones */
  document.querySelectorAll('button[data-porc]').forEach(
    (boton) => {
      boton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        /* Asignamos la clase almacenada en "data-class" */
        circulo.className.baseVal = e.target.dataset.class;
        /* Mostramos el porcentaje almacenado en "data-porc" */
        porc.innerHTML = e.target.dataset.porc + "%";
      });
    }
  );
  /* Simulamos click en el botón preselecionado */
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('button[data-porc][selected]').click();
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
.single-chart {
  width: 33%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
  
.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}

.percentage {
  fill: #SDFASF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  /* Habilitamos TRANSICIONES (y no animaciones) para
    las propiedades "stroke-dasharray" y "stroke" */
  transition: stroke-dasharray 1s, stroke 1s;
}

/* Ahora configuramos los estilos de destino. Las
  transiciones harán el resto */
.orange {
  stroke: #ff9f00;
  stroke-dasharray: 60 100;
}
.green {
  stroke: #4CC790;
  stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
}
.red {
  stroke: #e53c3c;
  stroke-dasharray: 20 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-chart">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
    <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
    <path class="circle" stroke-dasharray="0, 100" d="M18 2.0845
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
      a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
    <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">20%</text>
  </svg>
</div>

<button data-class="circle green" data-porc="100">8:00 AM</button>
<button data-class="circle orange" data-porc="50">12:00 PM</button>
<button data-class="circle red" data-porc="20" selected>4:00 PM</button>
```